# Passing multiple parameters to a controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

ok.  simple one that is wrapping my brain

I have a method that I have in the controller

```
public ActionResult Details(string strFirstName, string strLastName)
{
      return View(repository.getListByFirstNameSurname(strFirstName, strLastName)
}
```

How do i get multiple parameters from the URL to the controller?

I dont want to use the QueryString as it seems to be non-mvc mind set.

Is there a Route? Or Other mechanism to make this work?  Or am I missing something altogehter here with MVC

EDIT

the url that I am trying for is

```
http://site.com/search/details/FirstName and Surname
```

so if this was classic asp

```
http://site.com/search/details?FirstName+Surname
```

But i feel that i have missed understood something which in my haste to get to working code, I have missed the point that there really should be in a put request - and I should collect this from the formcollection.

Though might be worth while seeing if this can be done - for future reference =>

Comment: In the case of PUT request you only have to have inputs with names "strFirstName" and "strLastName" in the form. DefaultModelBinder should bind them to your action parametes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use hidden values in your form

```
<%= Html.Hidden("strFirstName", Model.FirstName)%>
<%= Html.Hidden("strLastName", Model.LastName)%>
```

and the model binder will do the binding

```
public ActionResult Details(string strFirstName, string strLastName)
{
      return View(repository.getListByFirstNameSurname(strFirstName, strLastName)
}
```

Answer (score 10):

For example, suppose that you have an action method that calculates the distance between two points:

```
public void Distance(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
   double xSquared = Math.Pow(x2 - x1, 2);
   double ySquared = Math.Pow(y2 - y1, 2);
   Response.Write(Math.Sqrt(xSquared + ySquared));
}
```

Using only the default route, the request would need to look like this:

```
/simple/distance?x2=1&y2=2&x1=0&y1=0
```

We can improve on this by defining a route that allows you to specify the parameters in a cleaner format.

Add this code inside the `RegisterRoutes` methods within the `Global.asax.cs`.

```
routes.MapRoute("distance",
"simple/distance/{x1},{y1}/{x2},{y2}",
new { Controller = "Simple", action = "Distance" }
);
```

We can now call it using `/simple/distance/0,0/1,2`

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?:

```
routes.MapRoute("TheRoute",
    "{controller}/{action}/{strFirstName}/{strLastName}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", strFirstName = "", strLastName = "" }
);
```

or:

```
routes.MapRoute("TheRoute2",
    "people/details/{strFirstName}/{strLastName}",
    new { controller = "people", action = "details", strFirstName = "", strLastName = "" }
);
```

**UPDATED:**

This route should be placed before "Default" route:

```
// for urls like http://site.com/search/details/FirstName/Surname
routes.MapRoute("TheRoute",
    "search/details/{strFirstName}/{strLastName}",
    new { controller = "search", action = "details", strFirstName = "", strLastName = "" }
);

routes.MapRoute("Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
);
```

Comment: the second parameter the ActionResult is always null.  The url is kind of wrong too  /FirstName/Surname  which means that there should be a ActionResult for Surname.  I am trying to do both?

Comment: Could you post an example of url for your action?

Comment: Placing the custom route before "Default" route only resulted in a 404 error for me.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to use FormCollection:

```
public ActionResult Details(int listId, FormCollection form)
{
  return View(rep.getList(form["firstName"], form["lastName"])
}
```

Likewise, if the HTTP request contains a form value with the exact same name (case sensitive), it will automatically be passed into the ActionResult method.

Also, just to be clear, there is nothing un-MVC about querystring parameters.

Answer (score -1):

I also had the same problem once and what I did was use the Ajax call inside the jQuery function. First I selected all parameter values using jQuery selectors. Below is my jQuery function.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnSendNow').click(function () {
    var grid = $('#Patient-kendo-Grid').data('kendoGrid');
    var location = $('#EmailTempalteLocation option:selected').text();
    var appoinmentType = $('#EmailTemplateAppoinmentType option:selected').text();
    var emailTemplateId = $('#EmailTemplateDropdown').val();
    var single = $('input:radio[name=rdbSingle]:checked').val();
    var data = grid.dataSource.view();
    var dataToSend = {
    patients: data,
    place: location,
    appoinment: appoinmentType,
    rdbsingle: single,
    templateId: emailTemplateId
    };
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
    url: 'Controller/Action',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend)
    });
    });
    });
</script>
```

My controller method has five parameters and it is as below.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendEmailToMany(List<PatientModel> patients, string place, string appoinment, string rdbsingle, string templateId)
{ 
emailScheduleModel = new EmailScheduleModel();
AmazonSentEmailResultModel result;
List<string> _toEmailAddressList = new List<string>();
List<string> _ccEmailAddressList = new List<string>();
List<string> _bccEmailAddressList = new List<string>();
IEmailTemplateService emailTemplateService = new EmailTemplateService();
EmailTemplateContract template = emailTemplateService.GetEmailTemplateById(new       Guid(templateId));
emailScheduleModel.EmailTemplateContract = new EmailTemplateContract();
emailScheduleModel.EmailTemplateContract = template;
}
```

It is working fine in my developments.

For further details please follow the below url.
http://dushanthamaduranga.blogspot.com/